# how to do to get accurate result of rounding value

Tags: c#, rounding, math.round

`Math.Round()` not working properly

`Round(17.675, 2)` is getting 17.68

`Round(6.675, 2)` also getting 6.68

But `Round(36.675, 2)` is getting 36.67

same like `Round(38.675, 2)` is getting 38.67[image]

but when I `Round(28.675, 2)` is getting 28.68

I used all optional parameters, then also getting same result

How to resolve this ?
pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-8.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-int32-system-midpointrounding)) overload and specify the `MidpointRounding` parameter to get the desired rounding strategy.

[`MidpointRounding` is an enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-8.0) with these values (from the original documentation):

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AwayFromZero | 1 | The strategy of rounding to the nearest number, and when a number is halfway between two others, it's rounded toward the nearest number that's away from zero. |
| ToEven | 0 | The strategy of rounding to the nearest number, and when a number is halfway between two others, it's rounded toward the nearest even number. |
| ToNegativeInfinity | 3 | The strategy of downwards-directed rounding, with the result closest to and no greater than the infinitely precise result. |
| ToPositiveInfinity | 4 | The strategy of upwards-directed rounding, with the result closest to and no less than the infinitely precise result. |
| ToZero | 2 | The strategy of directed rounding toward zero, with the result closest to and no greater in magnitude than the infinitely precise result. |

The default is `MidpointRounding.ToEven`. This is why it rounds sometimes up and sometime down. I.e., it round the midpoint values to the nearest even whole number.

Also note that `double` values might not be what they appear to be. E.g. `36.675` could be stored as `36.67499999999999`. If you need a more reliable rounding, e.g. for money calculations, use `decimal` instead. The documentation for the [System.Decimal struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-decimal) says:

> The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors.

Comment: I'm using decimal variable only. then also same effect is coming. I tried in immediate window for debug. That time also same result.

Comment: I get `36.68` for `Math.Round(36.675m, 2)` and `38.68` for `Math.Round(38.675m, 2)`. Note that you must add the postfix `m` to denote a `decimal` literal.